# PowerShell - Use "Get PnPListItem" with a value parameter

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Just started with PowerShell - I wanted to get some list items from SharePoint BUT only those which have the value "true" in field "hidden"

So my Code is:

```
Get-PnPListItem -List O365GroupConfig
```

So the Question is - can I do a "where" like in SQL or somethin like that?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Take a look at [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-5.1). Give it a few tries and if it still doesn't work - update your question :)

Comment: But if you take a look at the [`Get-PnPListItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps) command, you can also see that there is an `-Query` Parameter which works as an filter as well. This is probaly much faster than piping it to `Where-Object`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! :)

Comment: Tried this: `Get-PnPListItem -List O365GroupConfig -Query "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled'><Value Type='Boolean'>Nein</Value></Contain
s></Where></Query></View>"` But didnt work :/

Comment: Well you point out that the `Value Type` should be `Boolean`. If I had to guess, the possible Values could be `true`/ `1` or `False`/`0` and not 'Nein'. Try again with the Value `0` or `false`.

Comment: If you take a look at [CAML-Abfragen in SharePoint](https://andifandrich.wordpress.com/2010/12/03/caml-abfragen-in-sharepoint/): You will find `Bei Ja/Nein-Feldern muß als Value 0 oder 1 angegeben werden. True oder false funktionieren nicht!` == Try with the Value `0`. :)

Comment: Thanks so much! Tried it again but doesnt work `Get-PnPListItem -List O365GroupConfig -Query "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled'><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Contains><
/Where></Query></View>"`

Comment: You have a whitespace between `<` and `/` in the closing `Where` - this might be a problem. Please try to describe what exactly doesn't work. What is your error-message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to reach that goal:

1. Query all the items, and store the results of the cmdlet in a `$var`. Afterwards, just filter the values you want, like this example:

`$filtered_var= $var | where-object {$_.FieldValues.MyColumn -eq $true  }`

2. Another option is to leverage the  **-Query** flag, as this example:

`$var = get-pnplistitem  -List O365GroupConfig -query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='MyColumn'/><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query>    </View>"`

This way you will be already filtering results at query level, using CALM

Answer (score 1):

`(Get-PnPListItem -List O365GroupConfig -Fields "HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled").FieldValues | Where-Object HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled -eq 0`

Worked! :)
If you ask by PowerShell about the paramenters of the ListItem the Value is "false" not "0". So, you have to know it ;)